# What is the recurrence equation for this multiplication algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

The multiplication algorithm is for multiplying two radix r numbers:

```
0 <= x,y < r^n
x = x1 * r^(n/2) + x0
y = y1 * r^(n/2) + y0
```

where `x0` is the half of `x` that contains the least significant digits, and `x1` is the half with the most significant digits, and similarly for `y`.

So if `r = 10` and `n = 4`, we have that `x = 9723 = 97 * 10^2 + 23`, where `x1 = 97 and x0 = 23`.

The multiplication can be done as:

```
z = x*y = x1*y1 + (x0*y1 + x1*y0) + x0*y0
```

So we have now four multiplications of half-sized numbers (we initially had a multiplication of n digit numbers, and now we have four multiplications of `n/2` digit numbers).

As I see it the recurrence for this algorithm is:

```
T(n) = O(1) + 4*T(n/2)
```

But apparently it is `T(n) = O(n) + 3T(n/2)`

**Either way, the solution is `T(n) = O(n^2)`, and I can see this, but I am wondering why there is an O(n) term instead of an `O(1)` term?**

Comment: It looks a lot like Karatsuba (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm). I'm on a train now, and about to lose internet connection; if the question is till opened in two hours, I'll get to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, if you'll compute the term `x0*y1 + x1*y0` naively, with two products, the time complexity is quadratic. This is because we do four products and the recurrence is, as you suggest, `T(n) = O(n) + 4T(n/2)`, which solves to `O(n^2)`.

However, Karatsuba observed that `xy=z2 * r^n + z1 * r^(n/2) + z0`, where we let `z2=x1*y2`, `z0=x0*y0`, and `z1=x0*y1 + x1*y0`, and that one can express the last term as `z1=(x1+x0)(y1+y0)-z2-z0`,which involves only **one product**. Using this trick, the recurrence does become `T(n) = O(n) + 3T(n/2)` because we do three products altogether (as opposed to four if don't use the trick).

Because the numbers are of order `r^n` we will need `n` digits to represent the numbers (in general, for a fixed `r>=2`, we need `O(log N)` digits to represent the number `N`). To add two numbers of that order, you need to "touch" all the digits. Since there are `n` digits, you need `O(n)` (formally I'd say `Omega(n)`, meaning "at least order of `n` time", but let's leave the details aside) time to compute their sum.

For example, when computing the product `N*M`, the number of bits `n` will be `max(log N, log M)` (assuming the base `r>=2` is constant).

The algebraic trick is explained in more detail on the Wiki page for the [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).

Comment: Yes, the motivation is Karatsuba, which reduces the number of multiplications to three instead of four. I'm just not sure what the time complexity is of the operations to divide the problem and combine solutions, which seems to be O(n). I'd like to know why.